# cppyy.ll.cast fails to cast char*

Tags: python-3.x, casting, cppyy

Let's assume we have a char* named chr_ptr from some external library.

I tried to cast this pointer to **char*** by using **cppyy.ll.cast["char*"](chr_ptr)**

Expected: **cppyy.LowLevelView**

Actual:   **str**

Other datatypes works well, this problem only occurs char(a.k.a. int8_t). Casting the pointer (let's say) int16_t is OK.

```
import cppyy
import cppyy.ll

if not hasattr(cppyy.gbl, "get_char_pointer"):
    cppyy.cppdef("""
    void* get_char_pointer()
    {
        char a = 1;
        return &a;
    }
    """)
if not hasattr(cppyy.gbl, "get_uint16_t_pointer"):
    cppyy.cppdef("""
    void* get_uint16_t_pointer()
    {
        uint16_t a = 1;
        return &a;
    }
    """)

if not hasattr(cppyy.gbl, "print_address"):
    cppyy.cppdef("""
    void print_address(void* p)
    {
        std::cout << "address is: " << p << std::endl;
    }
    """)

char_ptr = cppyy.gbl.get_char_pointer()
uint16t_ptr = cppyy.gbl.get_uint16_t_pointer()

cppyy.gbl.print_address(char_ptr)
cppyy.gbl.print_address(uint16t_ptr)

casted_char_ptr = cppyy.ll.cast["char*"](char_ptr)  # At this point expected cppyy.LowLevelView but I got str
casted_uint16t_ptr = cppyy.ll.cast["uint16_t*"](uint16t_ptr)

print()
print(type(casted_char_ptr))
print(type(casted_uint16t_ptr))

print()
try:
    cppyy.gbl.print_address(casted_char_ptr)
except TypeError as err:
    print(err)
cppyy.gbl.print_address(casted_uint16t_ptr)
```

The result is:

```
address is: 0x7fff58b64847
address is: 0x7fff58b64846

<class 'str'>
<class 'cppyy.LowLevelView'>

void ::print_address(void* p) =>
    TypeError: could not convert argument 1
address is: 0x7fff58b64846
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `char*` is one of those types that solely based on reflection information isn't clear in its intended use. There's a half-finished patch to allow fixing up functions/data members with what their unique meaning of `char*` happens to be, so that's coming, and yes, `cast()` is a clear case where `char*` more likely means `byte*` than C-string, so should have that as default.

That said, in this case, it should be fine to actually use `std::byte*` (or `unsigned char*` if you're not using C++17) to indicate what the result should be:

```
casted_char_ptr = cppyy.ll.cast["std::byte*"](char_ptr)
```

which produces the `LowLevelView` as desired.

Edit: workaround for `signed byte`:

```
cppyy.cppdef("enum signed_byte : signed char;")
casted_char_ptr = cppyy.ll.cast["signed_byte*"](char_ptr)
casted_char_ptr[0] = -1
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately casting another type is not a good solution for me. Getting LowLevelView is not my main problem. I want to get-set the value of the pointer.

`cppyy.ll.cast["std::byte*"](char_ptr)[0] = -1` produces `ValueError: integer to character: value -5 not in range [0,255]`

Comment: In that case, ideally an `int8_t` should be used. I know that doesn't work (Cling does not provide the unresolved typedef, so it resolved to `char` before binding happens). Above as been updated with an alternative workaround. Aside, you could also assign `-1 % 256`.